# Do any denominations consider the writings of any Apostolic or ante-Nicene Father to be inspired?

Tags: denomination-survey, inspiration, apostolic-fathers, pre-nicene-fathers

Do any denominations consider the writings of any [Apostolic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apostolic_Fathers) or [ante-Nicene](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Ante-Nicene_Fathers) Father to be inspired and authoritative to establish doctrines? If so, what criteria are used to make such a determination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Coptic Orthodox Church considers 1 & 2 Clement part of the canon of scripture.

The Ethiopic Orthodox Church has a slightly more complicated relationship with 1 & 2 Clement (see [here](https://www.euclid.int/papers/Anke%20Wanger%20-%20Canon%20in%20the%20EOTC.pdf)); at the very least, portions of the Clementine writings are included in the Ethiopic New Testament.

A summary of New Testament canons by denomination is available [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Books_of_the_Bible#New_Testament)

The Coptic Diocese of Los Angeles makes the following statement on its [website](https://In%20other%20words,%20the%20mechanism%20used%20by%20the%20Holy%20Spirit%20to%20make%20His%20will%20known%20was%20through%20the%20Council%20of%20the%20Church%20leaders.%20This%20was%20the%20understanding%20of%20the%20early%20Church%20from%20the%20time%20of%20James%20letter%20to%20the%20gentiles%20all%20the%20way%20until%20the%20protestant%20reformers,%20a%20church%20span%20of%20some%201500%20years.%20It%20is%20also%20the%20mechanism%20used%20to%20canonize%20scripture:%20The%20Holy%20Spirit%20descended%20upon%20and%20acted%20through%20the%20Councils%20to%20enable%20the%20Church%20to%20authorize%20Her%20Scriptures.%20%20Those%20who%20believe%20in%20a%20sola%20scriptura%20position%20are%20in%20a%20hopeless%20quandary:%20If%20one%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20trust%20in%20the%20Authority%20of%20the%20Holy%20Spirit%20acting%20through%20Church%20Council,%20then%20one%20has%20no%20assurance%20that%20the%20Bible%20contains%20all%20the%20scriptures!)
regarding the canonization of scripture (after offering a review of the relevant history and councils):

> In other words, the mechanism used by the Holy Spirit to make His will
> known was through the Council of the Church leaders. This was the
> understanding of the early Church from the time of James letter to the
> gentiles all the way until the protestant reformers, a church span of
> some 1500 years. It is also the mechanism used to canonize scripture:
> The Holy Spirit descended upon and acted through the Councils to
> enable the Church to authorize Her Scriptures.
>
> Those who believe in a sola scriptura position are in a hopeless
> quandary: If one doesn’t trust in the Authority of the Holy Spirit
> acting through Church Council, then one has no assurance that the
> Bible contains all the scriptures!

---

The authenticity of 1 Clement (i.e. it was written by Clement of Rome) was demonstrated immeasurably well by JB Lightfoot (see [here](https://books.google.com/books/about/The_Apostolic_Fathers.html?id=oK0QAAAAIAAJ)), and is generally held to have been written about AD 96. For a well-written minority view, that it was written by Clement in AD 70, see Edmundson's work [here](https://ccel.org/ccel/edmundson/church/church.x.html).

The authenticity of 2 Clement is greatly disputed ([source](http://www.earlychristianwritings.com/lightfoot/pt1vol2/intro2.html)).